# Controller routing issue with with spring boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm fairly new to this. I have a web application that reads blog posts from a database and displays it on the page.

when im at `http://localhost:8080/`  for isntance i click on a blog post which opens at `http://localhost:8080/posts/6` for example. when when i want to click on anything in the nav to return to `http://localhost:8080/`, i get this instead `http://localhost:8080/posts/index` with an error.

Home Controller

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
  private static final String IMAGES_DIRECTORY = "/RDD-GHS/io.blog-master/images";

  @Autowired
  private PostRepository postRepository;

  @RequestMapping(value = { "/", "/index" })
  public String index(Model model) {
    List<Post> latest5Posts = this.postRepository.findTop5ByOrderByCreatedAtDesc();
    model.addAttribute("latest5Posts", latest5Posts);

    List<Post> latest3Posts = 
latest5Posts.stream().limit(3).collect(Collectors.toList());

    model.addAttribute("latest3Posts", latest3Posts);

    return "index"; // "Normal use"
}

@GetMapping("posts/{id}")
public String showPost(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) throws Throwable {
    Post post = postRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(new Supplier<Throwable>() {
        public Throwable get() {
            return new RuntimeException("Post not found");
        }
    });
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(post.getCreatedAt());
    model.addAttribute("formattedDate", formattedDate);
    model.addAttribute("post", post);


    model.addAttribute("imagesPath", IMAGES_DIRECTORY);

    return "/view";
  }

}
```

Post Controller

```
@Controller
public class PostsController {
  @Autowired
  private PostService postService;

  @Autowired
  private PostRepository postRepository;

  @RequestMapping(value= { "/" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
  public String indexView(Model model) {
    List<Post> pt = new ArrayList<Post>();
    model.addAttribute("posts", postRepository.findTop5ByOrderByCreatedAtDesc().get(pt.size()));
        
    model.addAttribute("posts5", postRepository.findTop5ByOrderByCreatedAtDesc().stream().limit(3).collect(Collectors.toList()));

    return "index";
  }
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: Can you please reformat your code and remove any code that's commented out?  It's really tough to tell what's wrong otherwise.  For example, your PostsController is missing @Controller in the sample provided, but it's likely a copy-paste error.

Comment: Also, will you please remove **"/"** from your Home controller? You are creating multiple redirection for same method.